# PHP members page carrying down to new line

Tags: php

I have a page on my site that shows a member directory. I want the members to be listed 3 per row, before it goes to the next row. The code I have, does this for the very first row - but on the second row, its all on one line and doesnt carry down.

The profiles are showing up like this:

```
uuu

uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
```

When they should be doing this:

```
uuu

uuu

uuu

uuu
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><h1>Member Directory</h1></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <?php 
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            if (empty($row['profile']) === false){
                echo '<img src="', $row['profile'], ' "width="125">';   
            } else {
                echo '<img src="../../images/template/avatar.png">';
            }


            echo '</td><td>';

            echo '<a href="' . $row['username'] . '">' . ucfirst($row['username']) . '</a><br />';
            echo "Location: " . $row['location'] . "<br />";


            echo '</td><td>';
            if ($i++ == 2) echo '</td></tr><tr><td>';
          }
       ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` inside while loop.

Comment: You never reset `$i` after it becomes `2`. Btw, what should happen if you have 4 entries?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (++$i % 3 == 0) echo '</td></tr><tr><td>';
```

Explanation:

First of all `++$i` first increments `$i`, and then uses it in whatever is next, this makes for more readable code.

Second, the `%` is the `modulus`, which means it sortof subtracts 3 from `$i` until it is not possible anymore. E.g. `9 % 3 == 0`, and `11 % 3 == 2` and so on. This means we know that we have printed 3 rows whenever `$i % 3` equals `0`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><h1>Member Directory</h1></td>
        </tr>



      <?php 
        $count=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $count+=1;
            if($count%3==1)
            {
                echo '<tr>';        
            }           
                echo '<td>';
                            if (empty($row['profile']) === false){
                                echo '<img src="', $row['profile'], ' "width="125">';   
                            } else {
                                echo '<img src="../../images/template/avatar.png">';
                            }
                echo '</td>';

                echo '<td>';
                echo '<a href="' . $row['username'] . '">' . ucfirst($row['username']) . '</a><br />';
                echo "Location: " . $row['location'] . "<br />";
                echo '</td>';


            if($count%3==0)
            {
                echo '</tr>';       
            }       

        }
        if($count%3!=0)
        {
                echo '</tr>';       
        }   
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't reset the value of `$i`, so it kept increasing; another issue is that if you have only seven items, the last row should have four empty cells. So the loop condition needs to be augmented with a row completion status:

```
$i = 0;
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false || $i != 0) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo '<tr>'; // start of new row
    }

    if ($row !== false) {
        echo '<td>';
        if (empty($row['profile'])) {
            echo '<img src="', $row['profile'], ' "width="125">';   
        } else {
            echo '<img src="../../images/template/avatar.png">';
        }
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo '<a href="' . $row['username'] . '">' . ucfirst($row['username']) . '</a><br />';
        echo "Location: " . $row['location'];
        echo '</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td></td><td></td>'; // no more data
    }

    $i = ($i + 1) % 3; // advance

    if ($i == 0) {
        echo '</tr>'; // end of the row
    }
}
```